# Почему клиенту приходят неправильные данные?

Tags: java

Добрый день, отсылаю данные клиенту через сокет

```
int pong =1
DataOutputStream outD;
outD = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());// socket   
outD.writeUTF(pongIPLokalServer);
outD.writeInt(pong);
outD.flush();
```

А на клиенте получаю

```
InputStream in1 = client1.getInputStream();
DataInputStream din1 = new DataInputStream(in1);         
int pong1 = din1.readInt(); // получаем ответ
String pongIPLokalServer = din.readUTF(); // получаем ответ
```

Вот это pong1 = 930102.
В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Что на входе то и на выходе.

Comment: @VargSieg Попробуйте создать [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). На [приведенном коде](https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/446c2f348d304eee4b4583e24861feb7) ошибка не воспроизводится

Comment: Когда сервер получает данные то что приходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина была, в не правильном приёме данных на клиенте.

На сервере отправлял:

```
outD.writeUTF(pongIPLokalServer);
outD.writeInt(pong);
```

А на клиенте принимал:

```
int pong1 = din1.readInt(); // получаем ответ
String pongIPLokalServer = din.readUTF(); // получаем ответ
```

Правильно принимать надо так как и отправляешь:

```
String pongIPLokalServer = din.readUTF(); // получаем ответ
int pong1 = din1.readInt(); // получаем ответ
```

Answer (score 5):

В pong1 читаете, а pong выводите.